# What's the difference between to_a and to_ary?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between `to_a` and `to_ary`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`to_ary` is used for *implicit* conversions, while `to_a` is used for *explict* conversions.

For example:

```
class Coordinates
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(x, y); @x, @y = x, y end

  def to_a; puts 'to_a called'; [x, y] end

  def to_ary; puts 'to_ary called'; [x, y] end

  def to_s; "(#{x}, #{y})" end

  def inspect; "#<#{self.class.name} #{to_s}>" end
end

c = Coordinates.new 10, 20
# => #<Coordinates (10, 20)>
```

The splat operator (`*`) is a form of *explicit* conversion to array:

```
c2 = Coordinates.new *c
# to_a called
# => #<Coordinates (10, 20)>
```

On the other hand, parallel assignment is a form of *implicit* conversion to array:

```
x, y = c
# to_ary called
puts x
# 10
puts y
# 20
```

And so is capturing collection members in block arguments:

```
[c, c2].each { |(x, y)| puts "Coordinates: #{x}, #{y}" }
# to_ary called
# Coordinates: 10, 20
# to_ary called
# Coordinates: 10, 20
```

Examples tested on `ruby-1.9.3-p0`.

This pattern seems to be used all over the Ruby language, as evidenced by method pairs like `to_s` and `to_str`, `to_i` and `to_int` and possibly more.

References:

- [Ruby Issue 3680](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3680)
- [Variables](http://ruby.runpaint.org/variables)

Comment: Just noticed how to_ary provides way to pattern matching in blocks :)

Comment: *Avoid single-line methods. Although they are somewhat popular in the wild, there are a few peculiarities about their definition syntax that make their use undesirable.* from https://rubystyle.guide/#no-single-line-methods

Answer (score 24):

`to_ary` allows an object to be treated as an array, whereas `to_a` actually tries to convert the parameter into an array.

`to_ary` can be useful for parallel assignment, whereas `to_a` is more suited for an actual conversion.

Answer (score 14):

Quoted from [gabew's web space](http://gabebw.tumblr.com/post/7938215707/array-to-a-vs-array-to-ary):

> Calling #to_a will convert the receiver to an Array, while #to_ary will not.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > class A < Array; end

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > A[].to_a.class
 => Array

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > A[].to_ary.class
 => A
```

Comment: Neither "converts" the receiver. "Converting the receiver" would somehow need to change the runtime type of the receiver (the object instance upon which the method is invoked). The reason why `A[].to_ary.class` returns `A` is because the base implementation of `Array#to_ary` returns `self` and `A` inherits `Array`. So the correct statement is "Calling #to_a will always return a new array representation of the receiver, while #to_ary could simply return the receiver if the receiver was already an array".

Answer (score 1):

to_a, when called on an object returns an array representation of obj

Examples

```
class Example
  def initialize
      @str = 'example'
  end
end

a = Example.new #=> #<Example:0x105a74af8 @str="example"
a.to_a #=> [#<Example:0x105a6a3a0 @str="example">]
```

Hash Example

```
h = { "c" => 300, "a" => 100, "d" => 400, "c" => 300  } 
h.to_a   #=> [["c", 300], ["a", 100], ["d", 400]]
```

> An array can also be created by using the Array() method, provided by Kernel, which tries to call to_ary, then to_a on its argument. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_ary

so as far as I can see, the Array#to_ary src just returns the array that is passed in, as in

```
def to_ary
  return self
end
```

if I understand correctly, to_a is used for array conversion and makes its final return using to_ary. But this may not be true in future versions according to apidock

> to_a Returns an array representation of obj. For objects of class Object and others that don’t explicitly override the method, the return value is an array containing self. However, this latter behavior will soon be obsolete. http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/to_a