# Double splat on `nil`

Tags: ruby, hash, literals, splat, double-splat

My understanding is that a single splat on a non-array object calls `to_a` and then dissociates the elements apart. And since `nil.to_a` is defined to be `[]`, the following conversion happens:

```
[:foo, *nil, :bar]
# => [:foo, *nil.to_a, :bar]
# => [:foo, *[], :bar]
# => [:foo, :bar]
```

By analogy, I thought that a double splat on a non-hash object calls `to_h` and then dissociates the key-value pairs apart. And since `nil.to_h` is defined to be `{}`, I expected the following conversion to happen:

```
{"foo" => 1, **nil, "bar" => 2}
# => {"foo" => 1, **nil.to_h, "bar" => 2}
# => {"foo" => 1, **{}, "bar" => 2}
# => {"foo" => 1, "bar" => 2}
```

But actually, it raises an error: `no implicit conversion of nil into Hash`. Why does it behave like that?

**Edit** I am not asking about the reasoning behind the design. I am asking where my thinking is wrong regarding double splat.

Answer (score 6):

Well it's our human being super power to recognize patterns and predict things. However it's not always true. This is one example. Ruby is not consistent in splat and double splat. Your way of thinking is a good way to "remember" but it's not exactly the way Ruby works on splats.

See this [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8507) for more detail. In this bug report, Ruby's author Matz rather to remove the feature of being able to splat `nil` than add double splat to `nil`.

Comment: This is a good explanation - like the pointer to bug and views of Matz.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `*nil` works is because the splat operator works on anything that responds to `to_a`, and `nil.to_a` returns `[]`. The reason `**nil` doesn't work is that `nil` doesn't respond to `to_hash`, which is `to_a`'s double-splat counterpart.

If you wanted this behavior, you could monkey-patch `NilClass`:

```
class NilClass
  def to_hash
    {}
  end
end

{ "foo" => 1, **nil, "bar" => 2 }
# => { "foo" => 1, "bar" => 2 }
```

Comment: So, you are saying that not `to_h` but `to_hash` applies in double splat? I thought that placing a single splat is explicit class conversion, and hence it is `to_a` rather than `to_ary` (my understanding is that `to_a` is explicit, `to_ary` is implicit), but it looks like that part of my thinking was wrong.

Comment: Yes, splat is implicit, not explicit conversion.

Comment: That contradicts the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467395/whats-the-difference-between-to-a-and-to-ary). Is that answer wrong?

Comment: It also contradicts the very [weblog post](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/messages-not-types-exploring-rubys-conversion-protocols) that you linked.

Comment: Notice that the usage of `to_a` versus `to_ary` changed between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9, so you should not rely on old information.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I was mistaken. I've edited my answer to be accurate, although your attitude and your edits to my answer suggest that maybe you should have just researched and answered the question yourself.

Comment: Warning: this can change the semantics of using `nil` as a method argument (just spent too long debugging this). Using `def x(a = "default", b:2) p [a, b] end`, `x(nil)` will throw a deprecation warning and try to treat the nil as an empty hash of keyword arguments, rather than setting `a` to `nil`.