# What's going on with `method_missing` and `puts`?

Tags: ruby

I printed a collection of objects that implemented the `method_missing`  method. The following example demonstrates this:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts "missing method in #{self.class} #{m}"
    super
  end
end

bar = [Foo.new, Foo.new, Foo.new]

bar.each { |i| puts "#{i}" }
puts "====================="
bar.each { |i| puts i }
puts "====================="
Foo.new.to_ary
```

#### Output

```
#<Foo:0x00000000d62ba8>
#<Foo:0x00000000d62b80>
#<Foo:0x00000000d62b58>
=====================
missing method in Foo to_ary
#<Foo:0x00000000d62ba8>
missing method in Foo to_ary
#<Foo:0x00000000d62b80>
missing method in Foo to_ary
#<Foo:0x00000000d62b58>
=====================
missing method in Foo to_ary
./missing_test.rb:6:in `method_missing': undefined method `to_ary' for #<Foo:0x00000000d61e60> (NoMethodError)
    from ./missing_test.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

1. Why is `to_ary` called? (I think it has something to do with the way `puts` tries to dig down and provide some info recursively.)
2. Why does the call to `to_ary` (generated as a result of `puts`) not generate a `missing_method` error?  It is not supported by `Foo` (or `Object`).  All my `method_missing` method does is print the method name and then call `super`, so if `to_ary` shows up as missing, the call to `super` should throw a `method_missing` exception, right?

Comment: @Drenmi You are right. Question 1 is a duplicate to that question. But question 2 is a new question.

Comment: @nPn In question 1, I think you mean `to_ary`. Don't you?

Comment: Quesiton 2 is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467395/whats-the-difference-between-to-a-and-to-ary :-)

Comment: @Drenmi Sorry. I think I was wrong. Both questions were probably intended to mention `to_ary`. Then, your link answers them.

Comment: sorry yes that should have been to_ary in both questions

Comment: I will keep looking but I don't see the answer to question 2 in either the link or the link in Drenmi's comment.  Both the puts statement and the Foo.new.to_ary generate a call to my override of method_missing, and both should be passed to super, but only the one that came from Foo.new.to_ary actually generated the exception.