# Why does the Ruby Array class have to_a and to_ary methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are there any use cases in which we'd call `Array.to_a` and `Array.to_ary` on an object that's already an Array?

If not, why do these methods exist within the Array class?

Comment: ruby as a language is a huge proponent of "duck typing" so that you can pass any argument to a method that responds to a particular method so say `def something(arg); arg.to_a; end` now this method can accept an `Array` or a `Hash` or any other argument that has a `to_a` method. See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467395/whats-the-difference-between-to-a-and-to-ary) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Notice that Integer has `to_i`, String has `to_s`, Hash has `to_h`.

Comment: For example, I have worked with an API that returns either object or an array of these objects. It was convenient to use `#to_a` to be sure that as result I will get an array.

Comment: `thing.to_a` can be used to coerce to array in some situations, but not everything responds to it, so `[*thing]` can be used as well.

Comment: Regularity of behaviors.

Comment: As this is a pure-Ruby question I suggest you remove the "ruby-on-rails" tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are there any use cases in which we'd call these coercion methods (Array.to_a and Array.to_ary) on an object that's already Array?

Yes: in Ruby, you generally *never* care what class an object is an instance of. Only what it can do. So, you only care about "can this object convert itself to an array". Obviously, an array can convert itself to an array, so it should have those methods.

Slightly longer answer: if we don't care what class an object is an instance of … then why do we care whether it can convert itself to an array? Well, that's a pragmatic choice. From a *purely* OO perspective, it shouldn't matter. But there are certain operations that are implemented deep inside the core of the execution engine that *require* an object to be of a certain class, for efficiency and performance reasons. In other words, sometimes objects don't work, you need an Abstract Data Type.

For example, there are certain operations inside the Ruby execution engine that take advantage of the fact that they know about the internal memory layout of `Array`s. Obviously, those operations will break in horrible ways if you hand them something that is *not* an `Array` and they go poking around in that object's memory. From a purely OO perspective, those operations shouldn't know that, and they should use `Array`'s public interface, but alas, they don't. But, in order to give you (the programmer) an escape hatch for your own array-like objects, those operations will allow you to convert yourself to an `Array` first, by calling `to_ary`.

In other words, implementing `to_ary` means that your object is a kind-of array. Obviously, an array is a kind-of array, that's why it responds to `to_ary`.

There are other similar conversion methods in Ruby: `to_str` for strings, `to_int` for integers, `to_float` for floats, `to_proc` for "functions".

There are also their single-letter variants. The long variants mean "I *really* am an array, I just don't happen to be an instance of the `Array` class." The short variants, instead, mean "I can kinda-sorta represent myself as an array".

You can see that most obvious with `nil`: it responds to `to_i` (because it kinda-sorta makes sense to represent `nil` as the integer `0`), but it doesn't respond to `to_int` (because `nil` is *not* an integer in different clothing, it is something completely different).

The fact that arrays, integers, etc. also implement `to_a`, `to_ary`, `to_i`, `to_int`, etc. means that you can treat *all* array-like objects the same, polymorphically. It doesn't matter if it's an array, a stack, a set, a tree, an enumerator, a range, or whatever. As long as it can kinda-sorta be represented as an array, it will respond to `to_a`, and as long as it actually *is* an array (even if its class isn't `Array`), it will respond to `to_ary`, and you don't have to check *because it doesn't matter*.

However, note that these situations ideally should be rare. In general, you should care about, say, whether the object can iterate itself (i.e. it responds to `each`). In fact, most of the things you can do with an array, you can also do with any other `Enumerable`, without using `to_ary` or `to_a`. Those should be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Array implements `to_a` and `to_ary` because this allows for cleaner methods that coerce arguments into specific types.

For example, what if you had a method:

```
def foo(object)
  #does some work on object that requires object acts like an array.
  ...
end
```

and wanted to use this method on sets generated from somewhere else in your code.

One way you can do this is to cast `object.to_a` before doing the operation:

```
def foo(object)
  array = object.to_a
  ...
end
```

If Array didn't implement `to_a`, then you'd have to do a check:

```
def foo(object)
  array = object.to_a if object.respond_to?(:to_a)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's (among other things) to avoid having a special case for `nil`.

Let's say `foo` is a method that can either return an array or `nil`. The snippet below would fail half of the time:

```
foo.each { |x| puts x }
```

If `Array` didn't implement a `to_a` method, you'd probably have to write something like this, which in my opinion is a bit ugly:

```
(foo || []).each { |x| puts x }
```

Instead of this:

```
foo.to_a.each { |x| puts x }
```

In a similar fashion, `Integer` has a `to_i` method and `String` has a `to_s` method, and so on.